# globally declared variable is not accesible i n javascript function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have both angularjs and javascript functions in a single  script tag,

inside script tag i have declared a variable, that is accessed in angularjs function, but the same variable if i use in javascript function, its saying "undefined".
ex:

```
<script>
var a = [];
var i =0;
$.each(data, function () {
a.push({
name: data[i]['name'],
id: data[i]['id']
});
i++;
```

working fine here.

```
function addPeople(status)
{
sname=document.getElementById("addname").value;
for(var i=0; i< a.length;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]['name'] == sname)
        {
            inst_id=a[i]['id'];
        }
    }
```

i am getting the error as 'a is undefined'

can anyone help me overcome this?

Comment: Can you create a working demo of problem?

Comment: load second file after first file, synchronously.

Comment: @niyasc, sorry didnt get you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @YOU, after pushing data to that array, i am using it in the javascript function

Comment: @niyasc its is a complex code, i have just added what is needed, a[] will be containing a parsed json,  so creating a demo is vry difficult,

Comment: try changing `var a = [];` to `window.a = [];`

Comment: is the function `function addPeople(status)` executing before your `var a = []` ?? have a check @Poojanagarajrao

Comment: no angularjs is executing first and then the javascript one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You for all your suggestions, i found an answer my self, i wrote a code to fetch json again in the javascript function, i know it is not optimised, suggestions are welcomed, thank you